# Can't access variable in Flutter GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am trying to pull the variable named `_pageIndex` from a file called GetX `welcomeMain.dart` and change its `value`.

`welcomeMain.dart`:

```
class getPageIndex extends GetxController {
  int _pageIndex = 0;
  increment() => _pageIndex;
}
```

And I also try to call `_pageIndex` and change its value like this:

```
onPressed: () {
  final getPageIndex _getPageIndex = Get.put(getPageIndex());
  _getPageIndex._pageIndex = 2;
},
```

But I am getting error:

[image]

```
The setter '_pageIndex' isn't defined for the type 'getPageIndex'.
Try importing the library that defines '_pageIndex', correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named '_pageIndex'.
```

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is underscoring, which makes your variable private. Just remove it.

```
  int pageIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Thans for answer.